# Return extra fields of many-to-many relationship instead of another

Tags: python, django, function, view, django-managers

My question is based on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) example given in the Django documentation. My models.py looks like this:

```
class Wrestler(models.Model):

    name = CharField(max_length=255)

class AlterEgo(models.Model):

    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    person = ForeignKey('someapp.Person', )

class Group(models.Model):

    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('someapp.Person', through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):

    person= models.ForeignKey('someapp.Person',)
    alter_ego = models.ForeignKey('someapp.AlterEgo', blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey('someap.Group',)
```

My group list template looks like this:

```
    {% for object in object_list %}<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">{{ object.name }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ object.members.all|join:" & " }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, my extra field is the "alter_ego" one. Every person can have an alter ego, e. g. Chris Jericho used to perform as Moongoose McQueen. With this template, members would be listed as "Chris Jericho & Richard Ward & ...". My problem is I don't want Jericho to be listed as Jericho but as McQueen if an alter ego is given.

I guess there should me a custom function replacing my person FK if an alter ego is given but I'm still trying to wrap my head around it as I'm really a noob regarding all this.

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should add alter_ego to Person model and then modify __str__ function of Person which should return the correct name - alter_ego if it exists or username if not.

Comment: I thought about that option but I'm asuming a Person can have multiple alter egos, e. g. Marshall Mathers is known as Eminen and/or Slim Shady, Sean Combs as Diddy, P. Diddy, Puff Daddy, Sean John and and every Person could be part of a Group with a different alter ego.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove alter_ego from Membership.
2. Change AlterEgo class and add related_name:

   class AlterEgo(models.Model):

   ```
       name = CharField(max_length=255)
       person = ForeignKey('someapp.Person', related_name = 'alter_ego')
       group = ForeignKey('someapp.Group', blank=True, null=True)
   ```
3. In template iterate over members:

   ```
    <td>
        {% for member in group.members.all %}
           {% if member.alter_ego.group == group }}
               {{ member.alter_ego}}
           {% else %}
               {{ member.name }}
           {% endif %}   
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
   ```

P.S. Small task for you is to form string from names in template and separate with &

Comment: Thanks, worked like charm! The template tags returned someapp.AlterEgo.None hat first but that could be worked out. Still, this not exactly what I was looking for. Maybe I'm overcomplicating it. Your tag returned every alter ego a Person has, not only the one I would have added in the intermediate.

It should be like this: Person A has Alter Egos A and B. He was part of Group A with Alter Ego A, part of Group B with Alter Ego B. Person B and C have no Alter Egos. Example: My list should look like this: Group A / Alter Ego A & Person B. Group B / Alter Ego B & Person C.

Comment: @Everlong then you have additional dependency to group, which you can add to AlterEgo class. It is null be default, so when user joins the group he should also choose the alter ego he will use in the group (or you define it for the user) Then in the template you can just check if alter ego group equals to the group for which you output names. See my edited answer